# asp.net 7 razor pages 'Get' form submit not producing expected url

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages, .net-7.0

Goal/expectation: have a url that looks like: `/search/test`

Problem: I'm getting: `/search?myvar=test`

Cshtml

```
@page "{handler?}/{myvar?}"

<form method="get" asp-route-handler="search">
    <input name="myvar" value="test" >
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

Cshtml.cs

```
public void OnGetSearch(string myvar)
```

Hi guys, from my understanding setting `@page "{handler?}/{myvar?}"` should have produced my expected url format.

Just in case it makes any difference, I also have a standard `public void OnGet()` for accessing the page directly instead of via form submit. (The form is on the same page, and submits to itself but with the `search` handler)

I've re-read the docs a couple of times but not seeing what I'm doing wrong.

Can someone suggest what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you misunderstand the role of `@page`. When you supply a  route template to the `@page` directive, you specify a URL pattern that the page can respond to. `@page` cannot limit the format of the url generated by the form, it can only limit the format of the url that the current page can accept.

As the specifications ([RFC1866](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1866.txt), page 46; [HTML 4.x](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.3.4) section 17.13.3) state:

> If the method is "get" and the action is an HTTP URI, the user agent takes the value of action, appends a `?' to it, then appends the form data set, encoded using the "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" content type.

When you use the `get` method to submit a form, it will put all the values into query string instead of route. So you didn't do anything wrong, you just misunderstand the role of `@page`.